# Not redirect to login page after accessed to a NeededLogin action

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I'm new in yii2.

When use the url to call an action, it redirects to login page correctly.
Example on nav-bar

```
['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Đat san'), 'url' => ['/datsan/create']],
```

But, when use Javascript to get data from server, it does not auto redirect to login page. How do I fix it?

```
var vUrl = $("#datsan-url-create").data('url');
        $.get(vUrl, function(data){
                 $('#modal-datsan').modal('show').find('.modalContent').html(data); // update data for modal
}
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" id="datsan-url-create" data-url='<?= Url::to(['/datsan/create']) ?>'>
```

I checked Console, it shows below error

```
Forbidden (#403): Login Required
```

/.DatsanController.php

```
 public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['create', 'update', 'delete'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['create'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['update', 'delete'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                        'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                            if (Yii::$app->user->identity->isAdmin || $this->isUserAuthor()) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well You are doing AJAX request it won't redirect if You don't say so. I believe You want something like:

```
$.get(vUrl, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    if (jqXHR.status == 403) {
        window.location = vUrl; // or whatever login url is
    } else {
        $('#modal-datsan').modal('show')
           .find('.modalContent').html(data); // update data for modal
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bogdan. It does not work. Same error. I tried adding alert(textStatus); right after $.get(vUrl, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){  but nothing alert be shown.